# Finding a node using Json.Net through Linq for inserting a child node or deleting it

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

I have this kind of format for the Json data:

```
{
    "Name": "MainMenu",
    "Text": "",
    "Guid": "047bf56e75f44c14b56a4b84f3af6dbe",
    "ParentGuid": "00000000000000000000000000000000"
    "MenuEntries": [{
            "Name": "Home",
            "Text": "Home",
            "Guid": "1e3df5fb3d8e463b8f37e8ccdb291802",
            "ParentGuid": "047bf56e75f44c14b56a4b84f3af6dbe",
            "MenuEntries": [{
                    "Name": "About",
                    "Text": "About",
                    "Guid": "f476a3444e2943668d86433f4c88374c",
                    "ParentGuid": "1e3df5fb3d8e463b8f37e8ccdb291802",
                    "MenuEntries": []
                }, {
                    "Name": "Contact",
                    "Text": "Contact Us",
                    "Guid": "51b461ec6abd4aecb95cf662e8e15ae6",
                    "ParentGuid": "1e3df5fb3d8e463b8f37e8ccdb291802",
                    "MenuEntries": []
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "Name": "About",
            "Text": "About",
            "Guid": "6954d6f747ef4d2dae33de0f0efae9cc",
            "ParentGuid": "047bf56e75f44c14b56a4b84f3af6dbe",
            "MenuEntries": []
        }, {
            "Name": "Contact",
            "Text": "Contact Us",
            "Guid": "634cfb99b70b4395b94061ae4f082aba",
            "ParentGuid": "047bf56e75f44c14b56a4b84f3af6dbe",
            "MenuEntries": []
        }
    ]
}
```

How to find a specific node through Linq using the 'Guid' field for filtering?

Also how to add a child node('MenuEntries') in the selected node and delete this node?

Comment: What have u tried so far? Have you used Json.Net

Comment: I parsed the string to JObject and tried to use the 'Where' extension but can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Model :

```
    public class MenuEntry
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public string ParentGuid { get; set; }
        public List<object> MenuEntries { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public string ParentGuid { get; set; }
        public List<MenuEntry> MenuEntries { get; set; }
    }
```

And deserialize it :

```
string jsonString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/json/test.json"));
RootObject Menu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
```

You can then select the node in MenuEntries like that :

```
foreach (var item in Menu.MenuEntries)
    {
        if (item.Guid == "1e3df5fb3d8e463b8f37e8ccdb291802")
            {
               Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
               //=> Home
            }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this path but for some reason, the searched node wasn't returned as reference but as new copy of that node.

Comment: This might work for the child of the RootObject. I already tried to make some kind of recursive function to check the MenuEntries of children but the fetched node aren't returned as reference but new copies.